# requesting http.post in a loop not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I have below code that requests http.post in a loop of 100 elements but saving the data in DB only for first one or two records, remaining gets internal server error.

```
post(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(myUrl, data);
  }

myMethod() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.myJSON.length; i++) { // 100 elements
    // Some Business Logic and changing myForm values
    this.post(this.myForm.value).subscribe( dd => { this.saved++; });
  }
}
```

I tried with but no luck.

```
setTimeout(() => {
          this.post(this.myForm.value).subscribe( dd => { this.saved++; });
        }, 1000);
```

My environment is `Asp.Net Core 2.2` and `Angular8`. C# method is `async`.

How can I post all 100 elements in a loop?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're trying to save the same value 100 times and that value contains a field that should be unique? E.g., a `PK`?

Comment: Did you read through the internal server error? What was it?

Comment: All such constraints cross checked before posting. And same data is working for individual post.

Comment: It looks like you're posting `this.myForm.value` over and over. Is this right? How does that relate to the length of `this.myJSON`, if at all?

Comment: In my logic, i get myJSON[i], do my validation, if everything is ok patchValue to myForm, then calling http.post.

Comment: I don't know if it could improve the result, but maybe the forkJoin by rxjs could be the answer. It waits to perform every request before go on on the computation and you just need to pass an array of observables.

Comment: @federico , any code snippet would be appreciated...

Comment: you're getting an internal server error... this is clearly an issue on your server and not your front end. Read the server error and address it.

Comment: Same data i am trying to post 100 times which does not have pk or fk or any other type of constraints. It stores 1 or 2 records per one event trigger remaining throws internal server error. If I repeat the post, again it stores 1 or 2 then internal server error.

Comment: Triggering single http post on a button click 100 times with the same form values working and storing in db. But when I loop with i get this error. Internal Server 500 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal server error is a server error. I woul consider to make one request and perform saving of all elements on a server side

Comment: What if 100 different users post single record a time? Does it work? I could not understand the difference between 100 users post a time and 100 post from single user from a loop.

Comment: When you make 100 http requests in a row you force your browser and server to open and close http connection 100 times. This is an extra overhead which may be make internal server error occur, because some servers has the limit for simultaneously opened connections. Or it may be db related error because of concurrency violation, I don't know.

Comment: When you make  one request you open connection only once and save your data in one DB transaction (I hope), which is much more performant and less error prone

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle multiple request is using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) by rxjs. A forkJoin takes in input an array of Observable, then it returns a response when every request is complete.
In this case:

```
 post(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(myUrl, data);
  }

  myMethod() {
    let callsToPerform: Observable<any>[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myJSON.length; i++) { // 100 elements
      // Some Business Logic and changing myForm values
      callsToPerform.push(this.post(this.myForm.value));
    }

    forkJoin(callsToPerform)
      .subscribe(arrayOfResults => {
        // some operations
      })
  }
```

Comment: Same issue, no change in its behavior